# How do you add a customized color index for mesh3d plots in Plot_ly?

Tags: r, lattice, r-plotly

I can easily make a `mesh3d` plot in R:

```
library(plotly)
x <- runif(50, 0, 110)
y <- runif(50, 0, 1)
z <- runif(50, 1, 2)
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'mesh3d')
```

I want to color the surface based on the values of the `z` variable: high values correspond to red or orange, medium values correspond to either yellow or green, and smaller values corresponding to light blue or blue. **My Question:** How do I do this using `mesh3d`?

I have done something like this using the `wireframe` function in the `lattice` package.

```
library(lattice)
x<-runif(12,0,1)
y<-runif(12,0,2)
grid<-expand.grid(x,y)
z<-grid$Var1 + grid$Var2^2
df<-data.frame(z=z,x=grid$Var1,y=grid$Var2)
# Note: there are 144 observations and I want 6 colors, so I need 144/6 = 24 replications for each color
nrow(df)
nrow(df)/6
a<-palette(c(rep("blue",24),rep("light blue",24),rep("green",24),rep("yellow",24),rep("orange",24),rep("red",24)))
wireframe(z~x + y,data=df,drape=T,col.regions=a)
```

Comment: `plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, intensity = ~z, type = 'mesh3d')`. For setting the colors, I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

You can add a custom colorRamp like this:

```
library(plotly)
x <- runif(50, 0, 110)
y <- runif(50, 0, 1)
z <- runif(50, 1, 2)

plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, intensity = ~z, type = 'mesh3d', colors = colorRamp(c("blue", "lightblue", "chartreuse3", "yellow", "red")))
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks!